# Multiple button select scenarios

Tags: javascript

I have multiple scenarios if a specific buttons is selected. How can I reselect by clicking the button again?

SCENARIOS
(1) training only
(2) travel out NCR only
(3) travel out PH only
(4) training + travel out NCR
(5) training + travel out PH

Here's my code so far

```
<button class="btn btn-block btn-lg py-3" type="button" onclick="selectReimbursementType()" id="training" 
 name="training" value="training">
    <i class="fas fa-book fa-2x"></i>
    <p>Training or Seminar</p>
</button>
<button class="btn  btn-block btn-lg py-3" type="button" onclick="selectReimbursementType()" 
 id="outsideNcr" name="outsideNcr" value="outsideNcr">
   <i class="fas fa-bus-alt fa-2x"></i>
   <p>Travel outside NCR</p>
</button>
<button class="btn btn-block btn-lg py-3" type="button" onclick="selectReimbursementType()" id="outsidePh" 
 name="outsidePh" value="outsidePh">
   <i class="fas fa-plane-departure fa-2x"></i><br>
   <p>Travel outside PH</p>
</button>

<script>
  
  function selectReimbursementType(x) {
    var element = document.getElementById(x);
    var currentValue = document.getElementById(x).value;

    if(currentValue == 'training') {
      element.classList.add('is-active');
    } else if(currentValue == 'outsideNcr') {
      element.classList.add('is-active');
      document.getElementById('outsidePh').setAttribute('disabled', true);
    } else if(currentValue == 'outsidePh') {
      element.classList.add('is-active');
      document.getElementById('outsideNcr').setAttribute('disabled', true);
    }
  }
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oy0zh4ws/2/

Comment: Do you need this button behavior? - https://ibb.co/FzbJqHC

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov sort of. if outside travel NCR is disselect, the disabled button should be enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the `toggle()` and `toggleAttribute()` methods.

Just use this js code:

```
function selectReimbursementType(x) {
  var element = document.getElementById(x);
  var currentValue = document.getElementById(x).value;
  var ncr = document.getElementById('outsidePh');
  var ph = document.getElementById('outsideNcr');

  if(currentValue == 'training') {
    element.classList.toggle('is-active');
  } else if(currentValue == 'outsideNcr') {
    element.classList.toggle('is-active');
    ncr.toggleAttribute('disabled');
    
  } else if(currentValue == 'outsidePh') {
    element.classList.toggle('is-active');   
    ph.toggleAttribute('disabled');
  }
}
```

Comment: @AlyssaReyes, always glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `element.classList.toggle` to toggle class.
2. Rest disabled state of elements and set again based on condition.

Try it below.

```js
function selectReimbursementType(x) {
  var element = document.getElementById(x);
  var currentValue = document.getElementById(x).value;

  // toggle elements is-active class.
  element.classList.toggle('is-active');

  // reset disabled
  document.getElementById('outsideNcr').removeAttribute('disabled');
  document.getElementById('outsidePh').removeAttribute('disabled');

  // set disabled button
  if (currentValue == 'outsideNcr' && element.classList.contains('is-active')) {
    document.getElementById('outsidePh').setAttribute('disabled', true);
  }

  if (currentValue == 'outsidePh' && element.classList.contains('is-active')) {
    document.getElementById('outsideNcr').setAttribute('disabled', true);
  }

}
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}

.reimbursement-buttons.preview-btn {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.footer {
  background: #7f7f7f;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.reimbursement-card p {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.reimbursement-card .btn.is-active {
  background: #32c5ff;
  color: #ffffff;
  content: "\f058";
}

.reimbursement-card .btn:hover {
  background: #32c5ff;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.reimbursement-card .btn:disabled:hover {
  background: none;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center form-row">
  <div class="p-3">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start reimbursement-card p-0">
        <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg py-3" type="button" onclick="selectReimbursementType('training')" id="training" name="training" value="training">
          <i class="fas fa-book fa-2x"></i>
          <p>Training or Seminar</p>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p-3">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start reimbursement-card p-0">
        <button class="btn  btn-block btn-lg py-3" type="button" onclick="selectReimbursementType('outsideNcr')" id="outsideNcr" name="outsideNcr" value="outsideNcr">
          <i class="fas fa-bus-alt fa-2x"></i>
          <p>Travel outside NCR</p>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p-3">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start reimbursement-card p-0">
        <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg py-3" type="button" onclick="selectReimbursementType('outsidePh')" id="outsidePh" name="outsidePh" value="outsidePh">
          <i class="fas fa-plane-departure fa-2x"></i><br>
          <p>Travel outside PH</p>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer also. Salute!

Answer (score 0):

`is-active` class has CSS and when a button is clicked then the button gets `is-active` class. So when the button re-clicked then the button gets same class twice. So easy approach is removing `is-active` class. As you suggested other below:

SCENARIOS (1) training only (2) travel out NCR only (3) travel out PH only (4) training + travel out NCR (5) training + travel out PH

These SCENARIOS can be reset by removing `disabled` attribute.

```js
function selectReimbursementType(x) {
  var element = document.getElementById(x);
  var currentValue = document.getElementById(x).value;

    function unSetOption() {
    element.classList.remove('is-active')
    document.getElementById('outsidePh').removeAttribute('disabled');  
    document.getElementById('outsideNcr').removeAttribute('disabled');      
  }
  
  if (element.classList.contains('is-active')) {
    unSetOption();
  } else if (currentValue == 'training') {    
    element.classList.add('is-active');
  } else if(currentValue == 'outsideNcr') {    
    element.classList.add('is-active');
    document.getElementById('outsidePh').setAttribute('disabled', true);
  } else if(currentValue == 'outsidePh') {       
    element.classList.add('is-active');
    document.getElementById('outsideNcr').setAttribute('disabled', true)    
  }
}
```

```css
html {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
      }
      
      
      .reimbursement-buttons.preview-btn {
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        color: #ffffff;
      }
      
      .footer {
        background: #7f7f7f;
        padding: 10px 0px;
      }

      .reimbursement-card p {
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }
            
      .reimbursement-card .btn.is-active {
        background: #32c5ff;
        color: #ffffff;
        content: "\f058";
      }

      .reimbursement-card .btn:hover {
        background: #32c5ff;
        color: #ffffff;
      }

      .reimbursement-card .btn:disabled:hover {
        background: none;
        color: #000000;
      }
```

```html
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center form-row">
  <div class="p-3">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start reimbursement-card p-0">
        <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg py-3" type="button" onclick="selectReimbursementType('training')" id="training" name="training" value="training">
          <i class="fas fa-book fa-2x"></i>
          <p>Training or Seminar</p>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p-3">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start reimbursement-card p-0">
        <button class="btn  btn-block btn-lg py-3" type="button" onclick="selectReimbursementType('outsideNcr')" id="outsideNcr" name="outsideNcr" value="outsideNcr">
          <i class="fas fa-bus-alt fa-2x"></i>
          <p>Travel outside NCR</p>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p-3">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start reimbursement-card p-0">
        <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg py-3" type="button" onclick="selectReimbursementType('outsidePh')" id="outsidePh" name="outsidePh" value="outsidePh">
          <i class="fas fa-plane-departure fa-2x"></i><br>
          <p>Travel outside PH</p>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```